# string.Format("{0:n0}") in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm trying to find an equivalent function to:

```
string.Format("{0:n0}")
```

in javascript.

Or in different words, I have a long number 10898502 and i want to display it like this 10,898,502.

Is there an easy way to do it ?

Thanks,

Comment: Use [jQuery.Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#numbers)

Comment: @Jon That's turned out to be a shopping question, which probably means this one fails on merit as well.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure Javascript solution, I would recommend the function below. It is courtesy of this SO Community Wiki entry: [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
var n = this,
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
    d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
    t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
    i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
   return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
};


console.log(
    (1000000.94).formatMoney(1, '.', ',')   // 1,000,000.9
);
```